# Read several observables of several variables of several objects

Tags: r

I want to read in data to R from a file. In this file I have a lot of devices and each time a lot of measurement points (current against voltage) per device (identified by SN at the beginning). Hence, per device I have two different sets of meassurements:

```
Before:
SN Temp rad grid grid_pos M Ubias Id M(for_1/M_dM/dV) 1/M_dM/dV
0711006316 0 0 47 1 1.000562 29.949368 -0.024111 0.999974 0.011783
0711006316 0 0 47 1 1.00222 54.997185 0.00171 1.001218 0.03954

After:
SN Temp rad grid grid_pos M Ubias Id 1/M_dM/dV
0711006316 0 0 47 1 31.1330427146 315.723640081 0.95654705303 2.90068387639
0711006316 0 0 47 1 32.4380778593 317.136008883 0.992233239064 2.93656451266
0711006316 0 0 47 1 33.8091346758 318.548377685 1.02972478771 2.97426034878
0711006316 0 0 47 1 35.2513676252 319.960746486 1.06916264771 3.01391310149
0711006316 0 0 47 1 36.7704819283 321.373115288 1.11070282833 3.05567963014


Before:
SN Temp rad grid grid_pos M Ubias Id M(for_1/M_dM/dV) 1/M_dM/dV
0711006319 0 0 47 1 1.000560 29.942378 -0.024012 0.999321 0.011782
0711006319 0 0 47 1 1.00223 54.997155 0.00170 1.001218 0.03954
0711006319 0 0 47 1 1.00286 56.747125 0.0018 1.001421 0.04671

After:
SN Temp rad grid grid_pos M Ubias Id 1/M_dM/dV
0711006319 0 0 47 1 31.1330422116 315.727640051 0.95655702303 2.90068287633
0711006319 0 0 47 1 32.6382778523 317.138008287 0.992233219078 2.95686421961
0711006319 0 0 47 1 33.8091346758 318.548377685 1.02972478771 2.98426037887
0711006319 0 0 47 1 37.2513276222 319.990742488 1.03956224774 3.01321314158
```

I know how to read in data in general: But I don't how to handle this stuff. Took me even some days in C++. In the far future I want to pass it directly from C++ to R but for the moment I want to get familiar with R. I'm having trouble with the format of the file as following: I don't know how to separate the different devices. And by keeping together their two sets of measurement points (before/after).

Bottom line: I would like to handle this data as similar as in C++ where I would store both sets of measurement points separately into a vector representing each device. How to do this in R?

PS: I changed my data as following:

```
Before:
(...)
912009897 1.00324 19.9895
912009897 1.01954 79.9714
912009897 1.02694 84.982
912009897 243.522 359.998
912009897 295.017 361.998
912009897 370.227 364.001
912009897 489.931 365.999
912009897 709.234 368
912009897 1235.31 370
912009897 3939.82 372.001
912009912 0.998576 19.9797
912009912 1.70584 169.929
912009912 1.96067 179.926
912009912 2.28553 189.926
912009912 23.2988 305.969
912009912 49.2436 331.969
912009912 52.6625 333.961
912009912 56.4583 335.971
912009912 462.716 369.983
912009912 651.679 371.975
912009912 1074.7 373.985
912009912 2740.88 375.986
912009895 1.00474 49.9612
912009895 1.005 29.9478
912009895 1.00504 54.9601
912009895 1.00524 19.9774
912009895 1.00598 59.9602
912009895 1.00962 64.9591
912009895 1.01166 69.9575
912009895 1.01368 74.9605
912009895 1.01877 79.9679
(...)

After:
(...)
711006316 1.00056 29.9494
711006316 1.00222 54.9972
711006316 1.00241 34.9388
711006316 1.00314 59.9988
711006316 2.68367 199.964
711006316 3.17968 209.963
711006316 3.79324 219.952
711006316 4.55159 229.942
711006316 5.50147 239.946
711006316 598.444 369.932
711006316 935.255 371.926
711006316 1940.84 373.938
711006317 0.998282 34.9308
711006317 0.998532 39.9208
711006317 1.00056 44.9126
711006317 1.00126 54.9591
711006317 1.00339 59.9696
711006317 1.04151 99.9741
711006317 204.89 359.954
711006317 1133.84 371.958
711006317 2794.96 373.963
711006319 1.00166 24.9969
711006319 1.03296 95.0028
711006319 1.04324 100.002
711006319 1.07155 110.005
711006319 1.11089 120
711006319 1.17016 129.988
(...)
```

Now I only need to know how I can match devices and data points together out of this tables. E.g. the device with the SN/ID 711006319 has six data points for the "after"-case so in R I want to fit only these six data points. And also the same for the device with SN/ID 711006317 with 9 data points. So I have to extract the according data points somehow out of this table and assign them to the proper devices. In the end I want to fit each device separately with its very own data points:

[image: Extract devices separately out of the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really help to have a reproducible example of what your input(s) is/are and what your goal is in terms of how you want the data.

If your question is about formatting the data, generally good practice (as I've understood and used it) is that each row should be a single observation/data point, with each column as a variable or observation id. So if all of your "before" observations have exactly the same variables and all of your "after" observations have the same variables (across devices), you can save your data as two tables, one `before` and one `after`, each with a column for device id (your "SN" above) and a single data point of all the respective variables per row, then just read the two separate tables into R with `read.table()` or `read.csv()`. If you want to be able to easily match before-and-after observations between the two tables, you can create columns `before$id` and `after$id` that correspond, and use `match()` to work between them.

I say this because it looks like your `before` and `after` have different numbers of observations and different numbers of variables - but if you have mostly the same variables (looks like this may be the case) then you may want to put it all into one table, with an additional id column for whether it's a "before" or an "after" observation, and just have `NA` values for whichever variables are not present in one dataset or the other. Sort of depends on what you want to do.

If you want more on using the "long" format within R, check out the [tidyr](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org) page.

Edit:

Without knowing your input data format (Are those four different tables in your example that have to be read in separately? Can you you input all of your "before" data combined as one table or are you asking how to combine it in R?) and your goals for the data (which will determine the kind of data structure you need), it's hard to be helpful. However, here's a guess, assuming you want it all in one dataset (you can subset/aggregate/model afterwards according to device, yes, but that would be a different question):

```
#
# create example data
#
before.df <- data.frame("SN" = c(1, 2), "rad" = 0, "grid" = 47, "M" = c(1.000562, 1.00222), "extra" = c(24, 9))

after.df <- data.frame("SN" = c(1, 1, 2, 2), "rad" = 0, "grid" = 47, 
                    "M" = c(31.1330427146, 32.4380778593, 33.8091346758, 36.7704819283))

#
# create empty "extra" column in after.df to match before.df
#
after.df$extra <- NA

#
# create "time" id in each dataset to indicate before/after observations    
#
before.df$time <- 0
after.df$time <- 1

combined.df <- rbind(before.df, after.df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have a lot of measurement data points each for voltage and current. So voltage/current should be variables and the data points the observables. At least R states that when reading them. And an object is my device. The background is: I have more than 10k devices and for each about 30 corresponding measurement data points (current against voltage). So for each device a separate file is really strange. But I can output the data in every way I want because I generate them via C++ And I already googled a lot but I didn't find a proper way to go..nor anything else

Comment: Have edited the answer based on your additional info - but it would really help to have a small reproducible example of what you've got and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Above is an example (just less data points and less devices), the goal is not quite clear because I do not know how exactly I need the data. I want to fit each device so I guess I can separate the measurements into two tables (before and after). And then I have the same example as on the tidy page under "Multiple variables stored in one column". As long as I can fit each device separately from the others? I'll check out if R can create separate objects with according data points out of a general table.

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear (at least to me) what you're asking how to do. I've tried to put up some code to give a possible pointer (based on your comment above that you can output one "before" and one "after" table) - but you may want to read up some more on basic R data structures and commands and think about what _specifically_ you want and don't know how to do.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I just update my original question, I guess it will be quite clear then.

Comment: Ah, you edited your post. Will have a look at it! Thank you!

Comment: On https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r it has already been answered. Will try to get along with the advices there. Will maybe return when I struggle. Thanks so far!

Comment: I still didn't find a proper solution. But I have a simple idea how it could be the most easiest way: Can R read in the data in such a way that each time, when content of the first column changes a new data frame/table will be created? Instead of packing all the data into one frame?

Comment: what a journey..   I found in my book that the example Rail is quite the same I'm looking for. In my case rail is serial number and travel is amplification and then I have one further variable.

Comment: Next step: The package plyr seems to be the solution: "plyr
is an R package that makes it simple to split data apart,  do stuff to it,  and
mash  it  back  together". Sounds perfectly fulfilling my wishes :)